# Сниффинг hotspot интерфейса

Tags: linux, c

Ребят, не так давно начал изучать основы работы сетей
и в качестве практики пишу простейшие сниферы. У меня на устройстве
есть несколько сетевых интерфейсов:

- `ccmni0` - Мобильный интерфейс 3G
- `ap0`    - Hotspot интерфейс(раздача трафика)
- `wlan0`  - Wi-Fi интерфейс для коннекта к роутеру

Я привязываю сырой сокет к точке доступа (`ap0`), но не могу поймать ничего, что происходит с подключенным к нему устройством. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы запускаете Вашу программу с правами рута? Только он имеет право использовать сырые сокеты.

Comment: Да, от имени root :( Может код скинуть?

Comment: Не надо... Как работает AP имею очень туманное представление :-(
Это я так - для контроля спросил. А Вы не пробовали смотреть трафик tcpdump? Или хотя бы посмотреь netstat-ом - есть там что?  А то, может там и вправду ничего нет ?

Comment: Пробовал смотреть через tcpdump, да, через этот интерфейс проходит все, что делает подключенное к нему устройство в сети. Пробовал не привязывать raw сокет вообще ни к одному интерфейсу, в этом случае он также не может поймать пакеты с точки доступа (ap0). Ловит только то, что передают мои приложения через мобильный интерфейс 3G (ccmni0), трафик же подключенных к точке доступа устройств принять не могу, хотя в этом случае прослушиваются все сетевые интерфейсы

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `libpcap` в своём проекте.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что libpcap - готовый вариант. :) Моя же задача научиться понимать какие ресурсы используются для работы с сетью. Спасибо, что откликнулись)